# Bootstrap Tabs CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have Bootstrap vertical tabs that collapses to accordion when it is on mobile screen. 
The tabs' design are by default with a blue background, white font and the `onmouseover` is also default setted.

I can't find the css code to modify it. The only way I could do it, was to add a `style=""` tag like this:

`<li class="active"><a data-target=".KONTAKT">KONTAKT</a></li>` in the html. It seems like I can't write over the default design settings.

I would like to modify the tabs' design in the css and modify the `onmouseover` too. My tabs are named KONTAKT and ÜBER UNS.

(I have to mentionned that my page also contain a Boostrap top-navbar that is responding to the `.nav` tag in my css. So maybe it can have a conflict with the `.nav` of my tabs.)

**Here is the HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabcordion">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <li class="active"><a data-target=".KONTAKT">KONTAKT</a></li>
      <li><a data-target=".ÜBER_UNS">ÜBER UNS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="KONTAKT in active">My content #1.</div>
      <div class="ÜBER_UNS">My content #2.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the CSS I have for now, I can't find how to connect the Tabs here**

```html
.tabcordion {
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.tab-content {
  font-size: calc(12px + .99vw);
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.nav {
  font-size: calc(18px + 1vw);
  margin-left: -2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your load order of bootstrap and the css you're using to modify it. Make sure your custom css is included in the page after you include the Bootstrap CSS library. Also it's advised to create specific classes for your added styles so they can be unique and reusable like:

```
.nav.custom-class {}
```

Comment: thanks for these nice comments! So, supposing my order is good, what would you write to get css of my tabs? I have tried many option but there are just guess. In my case, I don't know what is the right css syntax to get the tabs style.